# ExpressJS why is my GET method called after my DELETE method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

In my express app, when the DELETE method below is called, the GET method is immediately called after and it's giving me an error in my angular code that says it is expected an object but got an array.

Why is my GET method being called when i'm explicitly doing `res.send(204);` in my DELETE method and how can I fix this?

Server console:

```
DELETE /notes/5357ff1d91340db03d000001 204 4ms
GET /notes 200 2ms - 2b
```

Express Note route

```
exports.get = function (db) {
    return function (req, res) {

        var collection = db.get('notes');

        collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
            res.send(docs);
        });
    };
};

exports.delete = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {

        var note_id = req.params.id;
        var collection = db.get('notes');

        collection.remove(
            { _id: note_id },

            function(err, doc) {

                // If it failed, return error
                if (err) {
                    res.send("There was a problem deleting that note from the database.");
                } else {
                    console.log('were in delete success');
                    res.send(204);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

app.js

```
var note = require('./routes/note.js');
app.get('/notes', note.get(db));
app.post('/notes', note.create(db));
app.put('/notes/:id', note.update(db));
app.delete('/notes/:id', note.delete(db));
```

angularjs controller

```
$scope.delete = function(note_id) {
  var note = noteService.get();
  note.$delete({id: note_id});
}
```

angularjs noteService

```
angular.module('express_example').factory('noteService',function($resource, SETTINGS) {

  return $resource(SETTINGS.base + '/notes/:id', { id: '@id' },
      {
        //query:  { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        //create: { method: 'POST', isArray: true },
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
        //delete: { method: 'DELETE', isArray: true }
      });
});
```

** UPDATE **
To help paint the picture, here's the angular error i'm getting:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array
```

I'm assuming that i'm getting this error because my delete method is calling my get method (somehow) and the get method returns the entire collection.

Comment: You should probably check `e` in `exports.get()`, but other than that I do not see anything wrong in the code you have shown here. Are you sure that your client side code isn't explicitly requesting the GET?

Comment: Those are the exports, how are they required, and what routes do they match ?

Comment: I've posted some of my app.js and my angularjs controller section that show i'm only doing a delete and not another GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Server side

You're removing an element from a collection in your `delete` function. This is done asynchronously and calling your callback when it's finished.

During this time, other requests are executed, this is why your `GET` request is executed before your `DELETE` request is finished.

The same happens in your `get` function, you're trying to find an element from a collection and this function is too asynchronous.

But this is server side only and it is fine, it *should* work this way, your problem is located client side.

### Client side

If you want to delete your note **after** you got it, you will have to use a callback function in your angular controller which will be called only when you got your note (if you need help on that, show us your `noteService` angular code).

This is some basic javascript understanding problem, actions are often made asynchronously and you need callbacks to have an execution chain.

Maybe try doing something like this:

```
$scope.delete = function(note_id) {
    var note = noteService.get({ id: note_id }, function()
    {
        note.$delete();
    });
}
```

Your code doesn't make sense though, why is there a `get` in the `$scope.delete`? Why not do as simply as following:

```
$scope.delete = function(note_id) {
    noteService.delete({ id: note_id });
}
```

### Error

I think you get this error because of what your server sends in your `exports.delete` function. You're sending a string or no content at all when angular expects an object (a REST API never sends strings). You should send something like that:

```
res.send({
    results: [],
    errors: [
        "Your error"
    ]
});
```

Comment: I think you're way off (Not trying to sound harsh). I load the page which calls my GET method. Then i click a delete button which calls my angular `$scope.delete` method. At this point, no GET method should be called as nothing is calling it in either my angular code or my express DELETE method.

Comment: What do you mean by this: `This is done asynchronously and calling your callback when it's finished`. There is no callback defined.

Comment: @Catfish That's the problem, you should have one defined, see my edited answer.

Comment: You have a valid point with this: `noteService.delete({ id: note_id });`